# Excel formula/macro for finding data with letters and numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of data in Excel that contains different values. I am looking for a formula or macro to distinguish the different types of data. For instance, I have a VLOOKUP for numerical values `=VLOOKUP(E2,TECH!B:F,4,FALSE)` but this only works for certain values.

For instance, this returns the value of E2 when it's listed as a 4 digit extension in the column. Some data points are listed as "i78990" or "n65778", etc. I want to return a value of "Chicago" when an "i" is before the number and an "Atlanta" if the "n" is before the number, etc.

Comment: You need a more comprehensive example/description of your problem. Please see HELP for instructions as to how to ask a question and provide examples.  AS a minimum, also show us what you have tried, and what problems arose from yur approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "LEFT" function in order to get the as follows: LEFT(E2,1) to get the first letter (you can apply that to all of your cells), store the result on a different column and preform the Vlookup from there.

For a more general case of separating numbers from text you can use the following algorithm:

-Break the alphanumeric string into separate characters.

```
  use: MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)
```

-Determine whether there is a number in the decomposed string.

```
  use: ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1))
```

-Determine the position of the number in the alphanumeric string.

```
  use: MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0)
```

-Count the numbers in the alphanumeric string.

```
  use =OUNT(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1))
```

or as a whole:

MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)))

you can see an example in the following [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx).

Comment: Thank you SO much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I can manipulate what I need from this. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark it as an "accepted answer" if it solved your problem so others could use it.